# How to get auto suggestion/auto correct feature using search api provided by AEM

Tags: html, aem

I m working on **AEM 6.3**, in which for the search functionality I am using search API that is provided. Please clear me how to get auto suggestion/auto correction feature in it. The expected output is, if the user search for any wrong terms a list suggestion should be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

There are various ways of doing it.

1. Search and promote provides this functionality OOTB. From your question it doesn't look like you are using S&P so this may be irrelevant.
2. The other way is to configure a Lucene Index for using [suggestions](https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#suggestions).
3. Use 3rd party JS framework plugins for implementing auto-suggestions.

1 & 3 are not part of core-framework so they are open for interpretation within the project constraints. However, using a custom Lucene Index is an OOTB AEM feature so I would suggest to look at it before trying other options.

In a nutshell,

- Define an index for covering the properties and content for your search terms.
- Enable suggestions flag for the index.
- Configure misc. frequencies for suggestions update.

That's pretty much it. There are API's to show the relevant suggestion terms in your searches.

The choice of implementation depends on what kind of search terms you are expecting and the consistency of data (spelling mistakes, suggestion correlation etc.) but it all comes down to your domain being rich enough to benefit from suggestions.

> Please note that the default lucene index already uses suggestions flag so evaluate it carefully before customising or creating new index.

Comment: Could you please share the path where the suggestions flag exists in the default lucene index in a vanilla AEM 6.3 installation? I am somehow not finding it.

Comment: Read this feature: https://jackrabbit.apache.org/oak/docs/query/lucene.html#suggestions

Comment: Thanks for the URL you shared, I read this, this does state about how we can create sample suggestions' specific indexes, however I was looking for any suggestions flag that may be coming along within a vanilla AEM instance and that we can refer to. Do you have any clues about the same ?

Comment: In vanilla AEM 6.3 the lucene index should have `useInSuggest` enabled. OOTB this may not suit your requirements so you normally end up tweaking it for your content.

Comment: You also mentioned that there are API's to show the relevant suggestion terms in your searches. Can you please share the method name or API sample code that provides me this feature in QueryBuilder API ( I reckon that's the recommended one? )